# Twilio Session Variable in Number action url

Tags: session, twilio

I'm setting up a whisper function in my call plan and can't seem to pull a session variable on the 'url' in the  action. Are session variables supported there?

I have this in my dial action:

```
<Number url="whisper.php">15551234567</Number>';
```

And my whisper.php looks like this.

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo '<Response>';
echo '<Say>Call from '.$_SESSION['source'].'</Say>';
echo '</Response>';
?>
```

$_SESSION['source'] isn't showing up.

I use this session variable elsewhere and store things in a database with it so I know it is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I went to Twilio support and they gave me this info in case someone else ever looks at this.

"Twilio's cookie handling is keyed by the combination of `From` and `To`. For the `<Number url>` request, the `From` and `To` will be different than the `From` and `To` of the parent call, so that's probably why the 2 sessions aren't being shared and you get a new session."

The the  URL action is not in the same session.

He gave me this as a work around:

"The most common workaround is to include the extra data as a query parameter, e.g.

```
<Number url="whisper.php?source=<?= $_SESSION['source'] ?>">15551234567</Number>
```

It's not very elegant but it works well enough for maintaining state during the call flow.

And then in whisper.php you would access `$_REQUEST['source']` instead of `$_SESSION['source']`."

Answer (score 0):

Each seperate number to number pair holds a separate Session and cookie jar as if the twilio "browser" is browsing a different site.  Therefore, passing it into the url above is the only way to post the value across the two different pairs of numbers.